# toggleclass() not toggling until after function is complete

Tags: jquery

I want to change the button to have a background indicating that the process is running.
However, when I run this I see the button changes color but does not apply the spinning image as a background until after the find has been completed.  Do I need to do something different to fix this?

```
               $("#btnFind").button().click(function () {
                    $('#btnFind').toggleClass('loadinggif btnStyle');

                    var filterVal = $('#tags').val();


                    if (filterVal != "") {
                        $('#MainContent_myTable tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
                            $(this).find('td:eq(0)').not(':contains(' + filterVal + ')').parent().hide();
                        });
                    }

                    $('#btnFind').toggleClass('loadinggif btnStyle');
                });
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Not one that will replicate my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.toggleClass` function returns a deferred object, that you can access with `.promise()`, and then bind a function to it's `.done()` method;

```
$("#btnFind").button().click(function () {

    $("#btnFind").toggleClass('loadinggif btnStyle').promise().done(function() {

        var filterVal = $('#tags').val();

        if (filterVal != "") {
            $('#MainContent_myTable tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
                $(this).find('td:eq(0)').not(':contains(' + filterVal + ')').parent().hide();
            });
        }

        $('#btnFind').toggleClass('loadinggif btnStyle');
    });

});
```

Comment: Exactly where I was going! Good call!

Comment: that didn't quiet work...  It looks like it was trying to change the class but I didn't get the spinner in the button at all.

Comment: @olimortimer if I add a delay I get the spinner but it still freezes while the filtering is happening.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle of your code, so I can take a look please?

Answer (score 1):

It will not work like that because the browser tab will work like a single thread application where at any point of time there will only one task running like running a js script, repainting the dom with changes etc

In this case when the button is clicked, a class is added to a button but since the event handler execution is not completed browser will not get time to update the dom changes to the UI, the following workaround tries to give the browser repaint thread execution time by delaying the scripts after the `toggleClass` using `setTimeout`

You need to try

```
$("#btnFind").button().click(function () {
    $('#btnFind').toggleClass('loadinggif btnStyle');

    setTimeout(function){
        var filterVal = $('#tags').val();


        if (filterVal != "") {
            $('#MainContent_myTable tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
                $(this).find('td:eq(0)').not(':contains(' + filterVal + ')').parent().hide();
            });
        }

        $('#btnFind').toggleClass('loadinggif btnStyle');
    })
});
```

Comment: this sort of worked...  I added 1000 to the end of the setTimeout function and I got the spinner to show up on the button but once it was doing the filtering the spinner stopped spinning.  Any ideas?

Comment: @webdad3 it will freeze because of the reason said above if it is a time consuming process then the browser will not get any time to repaint the UI... because the script is blocking the execution time